# Create associative array from 2 columns in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, associative

Can I make an associative array from two columns? I want column A as key and column B as value.

```
-------------
| id | name  |
-------------
| 1  | sky   |
-------------
| 2  | space |
```

I want a function that make result like this:

```
$ary=array('1'=>'sky','2'=>'space', ... );
```

Is any php function exist about this matter?

I'm using php, mysql and codeigniter.

Comment: It'll come out of your mysql query as an array/object that you loop through using a while statement.  If you then need to further put it into an array just insert it inside your while. But in a dataset as simple as yours I can see no reason to array it over just looping

Comment: There is no single function that connects to a database, retrieves data and formats it into an array with one column as a key and another as a value; you'll need to write it yourself.... have you tried? which part are you having problems with?

Answer (score 12):

```
$ary = array();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    $ary[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though you are using codeigniter, you are not required to use codeigniter's libraries. If you are willing to implement a PDO implementation you can do something like this in native PHP:

```
$stmt = $db->query("select id, name from mytable");
$results  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR);
```

There would be less overhead this way than with some other implementations, but it depends if you want to use PDO.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Codeigniter, use its result set helper method, then call `array_column()` to convert the two columns to a flat, associative array.

```
var_export(
    array_column(
        $this->query($sql)->result(),
        'name',
        'id'
    )
);
```

---

If you were just using PHP's native mysqli:

procedural style:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
var_export(
    array_column(
        mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC),
        'name',
        'id'
    )
);
```

object-oriented style:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
var_export(
    array_column(
        $conn->fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC),
        'name',
        'id'
    )
);
```

---

You can immediately iterate the result set object: ([Demo](https://phpize.online/s/7p))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as $row) {
    $result[$row['id']] = $row['name'];
}
var_export($result);
```

You can even use array destructuring in a body-less loop.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($mysqli->query($sql) as ['id' => $id, 'name' => $result[$id]]);
var_export($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($rows as $key => $value){
    $arr[$key] = $value;
}
```

Comment: For large datasets, it would result in better performance to fetch each single row instead of fetching them all and iterate over the result set.